# Best way to retrieve selected item from Kendo treeview within Angular JS framework

Tags: angularjs, kendo-treeview

I'm integrating the Kendo UI treeview widget into my Angular based app (using asp.net mvc4 framework).
I'm seeking advice on the best way to retrieve the tree's selected item, as I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it - `e.sender._current.text();` -  is best practice.

In my html div below you'll notice `k-on-change="vm.onTreeSelect(kendoEvent)"` , and the associated js event in `function onTreeSelect(e)` .

I find the current documentation a little weak at http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/TreeView , so what I'm looking for is two things at the moment:

1) The best way to get the currently-selected item from the treeview.

2) How do I know when I've reached the bottom leaf of my tree.

Thank you ahead of time of your advice, and please find some code snippets below...

My html snippet is :

```
  <div class="widget-content text-left text-info">
         Selected: {{vm.selected}}
         <span id="treeview" kendo-tree-view="tree"
             k-options="vm.treeOptions"
             k-data-source="vm.hierarchy"                                                   
             k-on-change="vm.onTreeSelect(kendoEvent)">
         </span>
  </div>
```

and a snippet from my javascript code is :

```
 (function () {
   'use strict';
   var controllerId = 'dashboard';
   angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', dashboard]);
   vm.hierarchy = [];
   vm.onTreeSelect = onTreeSelect;
   vm.treeOptions = {
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        }
    };
   vm.selected = null;

   activate();

    function activate() {
        var promises = [getHierarchy(), getCountries()];
        common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
            .then(function () { log('Activated Dashboard View'); });
    }

   function dashboard(common, datacontext) {

        function onTreeSelect(e) {
            vm.selected = e.sender._current.text();            
        }
  })();
```

Answer (score 5):

the best way to get the data item would be:

```
var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.select());
```

This will give you the item with all data attached. Make sure you call it on change event. this would work because e.sender is actually the kendo-tree-view in angular and the other methods are standard. also pass the kendoEvent as event argument.